# Invoking a function via Start-Job and switch parameters

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $Function:DbRefresh -argumentlist $DestSqlInstance   , `
                                                                 $RefreshDatabase   , `
                                                                 $PfaEndpoint       , `
                                                                 $PfaCredentials    , `
                                                                 $RefreshSource     , `
                                                                 $ForceDestDbOffline, `
                                                                 $NoPsRemoting      , `
                                                                 $PromptForSnapshot , `
                                                                 $ApplyDataMasks | Out-Null
```

The last four arguments are switches that are passed into the function this statement appears in, the position and type of the arguments that DbRefresh is called with are all correct. Despite this my job is aborting with:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'False'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound
```

clearly there is some nuance to calling a function via Start-Job with switches that I've missed out.
        + PSComputerName        : localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to adapt this to your scenario, but this implementation should do what you need.

```
[scriptblock]$sb = {
  function isOn {
    param (
      [switch]$on
    )
    if ($on) {write-output "on"} else { write-warning "off" }
  }
  isOn -On:$Args[0]
}

@($true,$false) | %{ start-job -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList @($_) }

Get-Job |Receive-Job
  on
  WARNING: off
```

Comment: This gives a "The term 'on' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again." error (It should be $on in the last but one line)